# Error in List Method saying MultipleActiveResultsSets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I have list which throws error of `'MultipleActiveResultsSets' Keyword Not Supported`.

Below is my list method

```
public List<News> GetNewsListForHome()
    {
        var list = uow.Repository<News>().GetAll().Where(x => x.Status == 1 && x.IsMain == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).Take(3).ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

Any help with my code will be great help.
Thank you

Comment: That is a keyword in the connection string most likely, so check out what you've configured there.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's true in connection string what should I do?

Comment: I don't really know. I don't know if this is simply handed to the SQL Server, in which case I'd look into which version of SQL Server you're talking to, or it might be first handled by the local .NET code, in which case perhaps .NET Core/EF Core does not support that keyword. If it isn't supported by one of those two, you might have to remove it, but then if your code depends on multiple active result sets, it might not be that easy. Perhaps someone else knows more.

Comment: Your connection string probably has MultipleActiveResultSets=True. What happens if you remove that keyword/value from the connection string?